# Multiple WHERE Clauses with LINQ extension methods

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query that looks like the following:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.UtcNow;
var results = from order in context.Orders
              where ((order.OrderDate <= today) && (today <= order.OrderDate))
              select order;
```

I am trying to learn / understand LINQ. In some cases, I need to add two additional WHERE clauses. In an effort to do this, I'm using:

```
if (useAdditionalClauses)
{
  results = results.Where(o => o.OrderStatus == OrderStatus.Open)  // Now I'm stuck.
}
```

As you can see, I know how to add an additional WHERE clause. But how do I add multiple? For instance, I'd like to add

`WHERE o.OrderStatus == OrderStatus.Open AND o.CustomerID == customerID`

to my previous query. How do I do this using extension methods?

Thank you!

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Two ways:

```
results = results.Where(o => (o.OrderStatus == OrderStatus.Open) &&
                             (o.CustomerID == customerID));
```

or:

```
results = results.Where(o => (o.OrderStatus == OrderStatus.Open))
                 .Where(o => (o.CustomerID == customerID));
```

I usually prefer the latter.  But it's worth profiling the SQL server to check the query execution and see which one performs better for your data (if there's any difference at all).

A note about chaining the `.Where()` methods:  You can chain together all the LINQ methods you want.  Methods like `.Where()` don't actually execute against the database (yet).  They [defer execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx) until the actual results are calculated (such as with a `.Count()` or a `.ToList()`).  So, as you chain together multiple methods (more calls to `.Where()`, maybe an `.OrderBy()` or something to that effect, etc.) they build up what's called an [expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).  This entire tree is what gets executed against the data source when the time comes to evaluate it.

Comment: I feel dumb not knowing I could do this.. You just saved me from so much spaghetti code.

Comment: Thanks, That helped me. But is it also possible that I will trigger any one of the where clause depending upon a certain variable? @David

Comment: can you use this with a select clause at the end?

Comment: @New_Coder: Of course.  The .Where() clause doesn’t change the return type.

Comment: its weird because when i do this: List<string> paths = db.ClientStatement_Inventory
                                                           .Where(x => (x.statementYear == yea))
                                                           .Where(x => (x.statementMonth == mon))                
                                                           .Select(c => c.statementPath).ToList();
It doesn't work. but if I only have 1 where clause it queries my databse.

Comment: @New_Coder: Define "doesn't work".  You may also want to collect this information into a separate Stack Overflow question, indicating the code you're using and the data you're querying and the values you're observing at debug time as well as the observed vs. expected results.

Comment: The best part is that the Query translation in the profiler doesn't show any difference. Both are identical.

Answer (score 29):

You can continue chaining them like you've done.

```
results = results.Where (o => o.OrderStatus == OrderStatus.Open);
results = results.Where (o => o.InvoicePaid);
```

This represents an AND.

Comment: You - and others - beat me too it, but this is probably the most readable way to do it.

Comment: Repeated where clauses are added to the query with an "and" operator in between.

Comment: This is probably not the 'cleanest' solution, but in my case it's the only one that worked so far. I had to add 'where' clauses based on selections in the UI.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this so that the Where's are "OR"ed?

Comment: You can have just 1 where with logical operators like And, Or and so on.

Comment: @HosseinSedghian please post some sample code for how you could chain logical operators like the OP wanted in a single statement.

Answer (score 18):

If you working with in-memory data (read "collections of POCO") you may also stack your expressions together using [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) like so:

```
// initial "false" condition just to start "OR" clause with
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<YourDataClass>();

if (condition1)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(d => d.SomeStringProperty == "Tom");
}

if (condition2)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(d => d.SomeStringProperty == "Alex");
}

if (condition3)
{
    predicate = predicate.And(d => d.SomeIntProperty >= 4);
}

return originalCollection.Where<YourDataClass>(predicate.Compile());
```

The full source of mentioned `PredicateBuilder` is bellow (but you could also check the [original page](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) with a few more examples):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class PredicateBuilder
{
  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T> ()  { return f => true;  }
  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T> () { return f => false; }

  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                      Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
  {
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.OrElse (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
  }

  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                       Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
  {
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.AndAlso (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
  }
}
```

**Note**: I've tested this approach with [Portable Class Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714086%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) project and have to use `.Compile()` to make it work:

> Where(predicate **.Compile()** );

Comment: Is there a reason why this wouldn't work with Entity Framework LINQ?

Comment: Works fine with EF Core for me, too. The resulting Predicate is correctly translated to SQL.

Comment: Performance issues.

Even EF Core 5 , will not be able to write optimized SQL query When using above Predicate . All of the table records in DB will be fetched in memory and then query filter work.

I reverted back to query = query.Where  approach .

Comment: @UsamaKhalil Did not encounter those issues in `EF Core 7`. The predicates are translated to a SQL query (check it by calling `.ToQueryString()` on the query) and executed in database. `EF Core` will then fetch the columns return by the query, not everything.

Answer (score 6):

Surely:

```
if (useAdditionalClauses) 
{ 
  results = 
    results.Where(o => o.OrderStatus == OrderStatus.Open && 
    o.CustomerID == customerID)  
}
```

Or just another `.Where()` call like this one (although I don't know why you would want to, unless it's split by another boolean control variable):

```
if (useAdditionalClauses) 
{ 
  results = results.Where(o => o.OrderStatus == OrderStatus.Open).
    Where(o => o.CustomerID == customerID);
}
```

Or another reassignment to `results`: `results = results.Where(*blah*).

Answer (score 2):

you can use && and write all conditions in to the same where clause, or you can .Where().Where().Where()... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
results = context.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderDate <= today && today <= o.OrderDate)
```

The select is uneeded as you are already working with an order.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `&&` operator like you would with any other statement that you need to do boolean logic.

```
if (useAdditionalClauses)
{
  results = results.Where(
                  o => o.OrderStatus == OrderStatus.Open 
                  && o.CustomerID == customerID)     
}
```