# How to use multiple queries on Entity Framework backed datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I have a form with a datagridview. The datagridview datasource is set to an Entity Framework data context.

```
_dc = New WarehouseEntities1
_dc.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = False
_dc.USER_MANAGEMENT_INFO.Load()
dgvSUMA.DataSource = _dc.USER_MANAGEMENT_INFO.Local.ToBindingList()
```

This works fine. I have a number of search boxes that filter the data and these work fine as well.

```
If txtUserNameSrch.Text <> "" Then
    Dim pOC = _dc.USER_MANAGEMENT_INFO.Local.Where(Function(c) c.USER_NAME.Contains(pQrytxt)).ToList()
    dgvSUMA.DataSource = pOC
End If

If Not chkbxIncludeDropped.Checked Then
    Dim pOC = _dc.USER_MANAGEMENT_INFO.Local.Where(Function(c) c.USER_STATUS.Contains("ACTIVE")).ToList()
    dgvSUMA.DataSource = pOC

End If
```

Again this works fine except that only one filter is applied at a time. I want to combine the `Where` queries if they are both set and so far I'm failing. I don't want to combine them in if statements as I have 15 different search controls. Instead I want to apply the filters to the results of the previous filter and then set the datagridview datasource at the end.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791540/multiple-where-clauses-with-linq-extension-methods) is similar to what I want to do but in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with executing the query up front, then filtering the results, you can do this. Move the declaration of pOC out of each `If`, so it can be filtered in each place.

```
Dim pOC = _dc.USER_MANAGEMENT_INFO.Local.ToList() ' database is queried

If txtUserNameSrch.Text <> "" Then
    pOC = pOC.Where(Function(c) c.USER_NAME.Contains(pQrytxt)).ToList() ' filtered
End If

If Not chkbxIncludeDropped.Checked Then
    pOC = pOC.Where(Function(c) c.USER_STATUS.Contains("ACTIVE")).ToList() ' filtered
End If

dgvSUMA.DataSource = pOC
```

Comment: If you have this level of access to UI controls, then you are executing your query on the UI thread which no apparent asynchronicity. You should look into executing your query on a different thread.