# String to LINQ expression?

Tags: c#, linq

How can I transform the string with the query in it into an actual LINQ expression so I can execute it?

```
if(email!= null)
{
    query += "x => x.Email.Contains(email)";
}
if (firstname != null)
{
    query += "&& x.FirstName.Contains(firstname)";
}
if (lastname != null)
{
    query += "&& x.LastName.Contains(lastname)";
}
return context.UserAccounts.Where(query).ToList();
```

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: Look up "expression trees". I think that might be what you need.

Comment: You should build `query` as `Func<UserAccount, bool>` rather then `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<your collection>.
    .Where(o => (email!= null)? o.Email.Contains(email) : true).
    .Where(o => (firstname != null)? o.FirstName.Contains(firstname) : true).
    .Where(o => (lastname != null)? o.LastName.Contains(lastname) : true).
    ToList();
```

Basically it means the filter will apply only when the condition is met (just like in your if sentences).

Comment: Or you can use simple `||` operator like `.Where(o => email == null || o.Email.Contains(email))`

Comment: Why repeat where 3 times?

Comment: Won't this add unnecessary where syntax to the eventual SQL or is LINQ smart enough to filter these out?

Comment: @MikeBovenlander the expression is just a query which is being evaluated (and optimized) when executed (I.e. by calling ToList()). There some posts like this one which explains it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791540/multiple-where-clauses-with-linq-extension-methods/8791596

Comment: @Y.S I've read, checked and tested this; The shorthand from your answer: `.Where(o => (email!= null)? o.Email.Contains(email) : true).` WILL generate an extra *unnecessary* `CASE` in the SQL statement. HOWEVER `.Where(o => email == null || o.Email.Contains(email))` will work like expected without unnecessary `CASE` statements.

Comment: @PatrickHofman you marking the query as duplicate is just wrong. Author asked how to convert "string expressions" into using actual LINQ syntax. The "where + if" was my optimization to the code.

Comment: @MikeBovenlander thanks for that, good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving your query as a string you could save it as an `IQueryable` (from the `System.Linq` namespace).

```
var query = context.UserAccounts;
if(email!= null)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Email.Contains(email));
}

if (firstname != null)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(firstname));
}

if (lastname != null)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.LastName.Contains(lastname));
}
return query.toList();
```

When you finally call `ToList()` the `IQueryable` is enumerated to a `List` of `UserAccount`.

Answer (score 0):

If the query is required with the combination of where clauses then every time result needs to be saved in query itself

```
var query = context.UserAccounts;

if(email != null)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Email.Contains(email));
}
if (firstname != null)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(firstname));
}
if (lastname != null))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.LastName.Contains(lastname));
}
return query.ToList();
```

Another complex approach could be to use [Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: *Another complex approach could be to use Actions* No

Comment: Missing a few `=>` above, at which point it becomes identical to KamielK's answer

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score -2):

Maybe I'm not seeing your problem correctly so excuse me if i'm wrong.
Why convert the string to a LINQ expression when you can do this:

```
var query = context.UserAccounts;

if(email != null)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Email.Contains(email));
}
if (firstname != null)
{
    query = query.Where(x.FirstName.Contains(firstname));
}
if (lastname != null))
{
    query = query.Where(x.LastName.Contains(lastname));
}
return query.toList();
```

Comment: if i understand correclty, now only one of the statements gets executed, however in my project it could be possible that only one is null so i have to execute both the others in a query.

Comment: No; you can chain multiple `.Where()`'s in a query. The query if all the fields are set: `context.UserAccounts.Where(x => x.Email.Contains(email)).Where(x.FirstName.Contains(firstname)).Where(x.LastName.Contains(lastname)).toList();` is perfectly fine.

Comment: You are calling `.Where()` three times and throw way the return value each time. What should this be useful for?

Comment: Why would you use `.Where()` three times if you can just use `&&`?

Comment: Query complexity @AlainElemia

Comment: This is really longhand way to write `return context.UserAccounts.toList();` and to give your PC some meaningless chores as punishment.