# linq query dynamically inside where

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, reflection

I would like to change dynamically a specific part of the query - depending on the result of if condition. I would be glad for your help:

```
if (someCondition == true)
    var ADDITION_FILTER_CRITERIA = && z.t.Name == Keyword
else
    var ADDITION_FILTER_CRITERIA = "";

var ToursPerDestination = await _context.Tours
    .Join(_context.CruiseDestinations, t => t.DestinationId, d => d.DestinationId, (t, d) => new { t, d })
    .Where(z => z.d.CruiseId == SelectedCruise.CruiseId ADDITION_FILTER_CRITERIA )
    .Select(z => new ToursViewModel()
    {                   
        Name = z.t.Name,                   
    }).OrderByDescending(z => z.Name).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: This question has been answered previously https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227653/content-date-does-not-start-with-date-and-end-with-as-requi/44227695

Comment: I posted a solution similar to what you are looking for today on how to get thoses IF's in the LINQ where, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962228/string-to-linq-expression/

Comment: PiJei  - your url goes to - Content '\/Date('')\/' does not start with '\/Date(' and end with ')\/' as required for JSON ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Func<string, bool>` and decide what it checks depending of `someCondition`:

```
Func<string, bool> ADDITION_FILTER_CRITERIA;
if (someCondition == true)
    ADDITION_FILTER_CRITERIA = (string s) => s == Keyword;
else
    ADDITION_FILTER_CRITERIA = (string s) => true;

var ToursPerDestination = await _context.Tours
    .Join(_context.CruiseDestinations, t => t.DestinationId, d => d.DestinationId, (t, d) => new { t, d })
    .Where(z => z.d.CruiseId == SelectedCruise.CruiseId && ADDITION_FILTER_CRITERIA(z.t.Name) )
    .Select(z => new ToursViewModel() { Name = z.t.Name }).OrderByDescending(z => z.Name).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks!!