# How I can filter IQueryable?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following controller:

```
public class EventsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICustomerEventRepository _customerEventRepository;

    public EventsController(ICustomerEventRepository customerEventRepository)
    {
        _customerEventRepository = customerEventRepository;
    }

    public IActionResult Index(int? customerid, int? pageNumber, string code = "")
    {
        IQueryable<CustomerEvent> customerEvents;

        if (customerid.HasValue)
        {
            customerEvents =
                _customerEventRepository.CustomerEvents.Where(x => x.Customer.CustomerId == customerid)
                    .Include(x => x.Customer).OrderByDescending(x => x.CustomerEventId);
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
        {
            customerEvents =
                _customerEventRepository.CustomerEvents.Where(x => x.EventType == code)
                    .Include(x => x.Customer).OrderByDescending(x => x.CustomerEventId);
        }
        else
        {
            customerEvents = _customerEventRepository.CustomerEvents
                .Include(x => x.Customer).OrderByDescending(x => x.CustomerEventId);
        }

        var page = pageNumber ?? 1;

        var onePageOfEvents = customerEvents.ToPagedList(page, 15);

        return View(onePageOfEvents);
    }
}
```

Note that

```
_customerEventRepository = customerEventRepository;
```

is my repository. It returns `IQueryable` form my. In the signature of the method `Index` I have a set of parameters. It's query parameters for filtering. Right now I have 2 (`pageNumber` is not filter parameter, it's for pagination), but I'm planning more. So this code is not very optimal. If I have more filter parameters I will be forced to make more and more `if` instructions. Because conditions don't work for `LINQ`. Maybe somebody had the same issue? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple WHERE Clauses with LINQ extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791540/multiple-where-clauses-with-linq-extension-methods)

Comment: I have addressed similar problems by using OData and exposing a view. Let the client code build create a filter url using odata syntax. It is a leaky abstraction *but* highly effective in situations like this. You can create an abstraction layer in your javascript code (assuming that is what the front end is wanting to use) around the odata syntax (a token type strategy works very well).

Comment: @GSerg unfortunately not duplicate. In the question that You have showed the speech about several `Where`. But I need ability to skip some `Where` if query parameter don't have value. For example if `code` == empty string, than I would like to skip `Where` and go to the next `Where`.

Comment: How is that different? `customerEvents = _customerEventRepository.CustomerEvents; if(customerid.HasValue) customerEvents = customerEvents.Where(x => x.Customer.CustomerId == customerid); if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code)) customerEvents = customerEvents.Where(x => x.EventType == code);`, and in the end `customerEvents = customerEvents.Include(x => x.Customer).OrderByDescending(x => x.CustomerEventId);`. That question tells you that you can chain `Where`s at any point later, which is exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, you want to build up the query based on multiple conditions.

`IQueryable` defers execution until the collection is materialised (for example calling `ToList` or iterating over the collection).

This allows you to build up the query piece by piece.  See an example below.

```
IQueryable<CustomerEvent> customerEvents = _customerEventRepository
                                               .CustomerEvents
                                               .Include(x => x.Customer);

if (customerid.HasValue)
{
    customerEvents = customerEvents.Where(x => x.Customer.CustomerId == customerid);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
{
    customerEvents = customerEvents.Where(x => x.EventType == code); 
}
// other conditions
...

// finally (this is when the query is actually executed)
var onePageOfEvents = customerEvents
                         .OrderByDescending(x => x.CustomerEventId)
                         .ToPagedList(page, 15);

return View(onePageOfEvents);
```

Comment: Thank you) It was helpful))