# Stacking where conditions with Lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

We generally add multiple conditions in `Where` expression separating with `&&`(`||`).

***Suppose, if I stack multiple where conditions is there any difference in performance?***

**For example:**

Is this line

```
dbContext.Students.Where(s=> s.Section = 5 && s.Marks >50).ToList();
```

Similar to

```
dbContext.Students.Where(s=>s.Section = 5).Where(s=>s.Marks > 50).ToList();
```

Note: Above line is possible as `Where` returns IQueryable which inturn has `Where`.

Comment: Why don't you try with a StopWatch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use two "where" clauses or "&&" in my LINQ query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664683/should-i-use-two-where-clauses-or-in-my-linq-query)

Comment: Try running a sql trace and you will see the sql that is generated by the linq provider as @Tolga Evcimen mentioned the IQueryable will only be evaluated when ToList() is called

Comment: @sr28 Actually it's not an exact duplicate, as the link you attached talks about the enumarebles on memory, and here PO actually is curios about from linqToSql perspective. As far as I understood :)

Comment: @sujithkarivelil Sure!! Im on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time your statement hits the db is when `.ToList()` is called. Hence what you do before that wouldn't create much difference in practice.

However from the perspective of pure mathematical performance, there should be some difference related with the translation process going behind those. Which can be understood by an experiment as @sujith karivelil suggests, or by some deep reading.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using '&&' and '||' operators instead of multiple clauses essentially results in 1 enumeration over the full collection once. Multiple 'Where' clauses means you will enumerate over the full collection, then the results, which could be the full collection again.

Comment: What you say is true of `IEnumerable<T>`, but this looks like `IQueryable<T>` - and most `IQueryable<T>` implementations (with the obvious exception of `AsQueryable()`) are "composable", which means that the operations are combined by the tool *before* issuing a down-level query to an external service (in this case, a database)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the use operator "&&" .. Because its filter the records at a single moment even used multiple condition.
But if you use multiple where statements it  definitely impact the performance because how many times you used where statement it hit the result query for filtering.